# How to put an embedded youtube video over the top of an image (as a frame around the video)

Tags: html, wordpress, video, youtube

I want to put an embedded youtube video over the top of an image so it looks like there is a frame around the Youtube video.  They are perfectly aligned horizontally, but I can't seem to align the video & image vertically. Somehow I need to add padding to the top of the Youtube video so it is lowered into the frame.

I'm using Wordpress and the measurements for the frame fit the video perfectly. I just need to lower the video into the frame.

Any ideas how to lower the Youtube video to make it align correctly inside the Frame?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to apply a margin or padding to the Youtube video HTML element (probably an `iframe` tag if you are embedding it)

So, your CSS may look something like this, depending on your HTML structure:

```
iframe { margin-top: 10px; }
```

You'll need to play around with the value of `margin-top` to make it align the way you like.

If you post the relevant HTML, I could give you specific CSS to use.